# Getting error xcodebuild exited with status 6

Tags: objective-c, xcode, xcode-server, xcode-tools

Running a test bot that's returning this warning and not creating an installable product. Anyone know what that status means?

This is the build error:

```
`xcodebuild[98753:3595809] [MT] DVTAssertions: ASSERTION FAILURE in /Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/IDEFrameworks/IDEFrameworks-9548.1/IDEFoundation/Distribution/IDEDistributionMethodStep.m:123
Details:  Assertion failed: contentPath
Object:   <IDEDistributionMethodStep>
Method:   +distributionMethodForSameAsArchive:contentPath:task:logAspect:
Thread:   <NSThread: 0x7fa7a9d157f0>{number = 1, name = main}
Hints: None
Backtrace:
  0  0x000000010a6dcacd -[DVTAssertionHandler handleFailureInMethod:object:fileName:lineNumber:assertionSignature:messageFormat:arguments:] (in DVTFoundation)
  1  0x000000010a6dc601 _DVTAssertionHandler (in DVTFoundation)
  2  0x000000010a6dc818 _DVTAssertionFailureHandler (in DVTFoundation)
  3  0x000000010a6dc77a _DVTAssertionFailureHandler (in DVTFoundation)
  4  0x000000010ac49f04 +[IDEDistributionMethodStep distributionMethodForSameAsArchive:contentPath:task:logAspect:] (in IDEFoundation)
  5  0x000000010ac49320 -[IDEDistributionMethodStep loadFromPropertyList:error:] (in IDEFoundation)
  6  0x000000010adb7f2f -[IDEDistributionDriver runWithDestinationPath:error:] (in IDEFoundation)
  7  0x000000010b3e417b -[Xcode3CommandLineBuildTool _distributeArchiveAndExit] (in Xcode3Core)
  8  0x000000010b3e7a78 -[Xcode3CommandLineBuildTool run] (in Xcode3Core)
  9  0x000000010a4a5931 (in xcodebuild)
 10  0x00007fff946d95ad start (in libdyld.dylib)`
```

Answer (score 0):

I had this same problem. My app links to a .framework, and my framework had the `SKIP_INSTALL` build setting set to `YES`. Changing it to `NO` fixed it.